# Solve for $x$ in $x\sqrt{1-4x^2}+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find out the value of $x$ in $x\sqrt{1-4x^2}+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt 3}2$.

I tried squaring both the sides but it only makes it more complicated.  Is there any other way?

Comment: [WolframAlpha offers a pair of solutions](https://goo.gl/MqGhxh), though it's beyond me as to how to derive them at the moment.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer it is a paid service of which I don't have subscription.

Comment: WolframAlpha is not a paid service. >_> In any event the solutions given are

$$x = \frac 1 2 \;\;\; x = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \frac 3 7 }$$

Comment: Double squaring will usually work (and does here), even if you have a bunch of terms to collect and maybe a substitution to make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $2x = \cos(\alpha), x = \cos(\beta) \implies \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\implies \sin(\alpha+\beta) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\implies \alpha+\beta=\dfrac{\pi}{3}, \dfrac{2\pi}{3}\implies \beta = \dfrac{\pi}{3} - \alpha\implies x = \cos(\dfrac{\pi}{3} -\alpha)= \dfrac{1}{2}(2x)+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(\alpha)\implies \sin(\alpha) = 0 \implies \cos(\alpha) = 1\implies x = \dfrac{1}{2}$. The other case that $\alpha+\beta = \dfrac{2\pi}{3}$, I leave it for you to finish.

Comment: @user654700: That one comes from $x = \cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{3}-\alpha) = -\dfrac{1}{2}(2x)+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(\alpha)= -x +\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt{1-4x^2}$,and you solve for $x$ to get that value.

Comment: This is cool. Like it!

Comment: However, one must note that this works only because the circumstances here are especially favourable. Doesn't look like a general method for equations involving radicals of second order. In any case how is one sure this has given all solutions? Why restrict yourself only to the fundamental interval?

Answer (score 3):

Double squaring gives
$$21 {{x}^{4}}-\frac{15 {{x}^{2}}}{2}+\frac{9}{16}=0$$
Valid solutions is
$$x=\frac12,\quad x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{7}}. $$